# A way to stream from a v4l2 device?

Tags: linux, video-streaming, h.264, theora, v4l2

I have a Arch Linux server and I'm currently using the mjpeg format to stream a security camera. The problem is that mjpeg is a bad format in terms of compression. It compress frames individually so the stream is heavy and requires a lot of bandwidth.

I'm looking for a way to stream using a format like H264 or Theora. I know vlc can do that but it's not server suitable.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: What's wrong with VLC on a server?  It has command-line and curses interfaces, so you don't need a GUI.

Comment: `gstreamer` - it's absolutely fantastic, and has a TCP/UDP server option, as well as `v4l2` bindings.

Comment: Can you tell me an idea of how to use gstreamer? Thanks!